# KVM size limit on total number of machines

Tags: kvm-virtualization

There's an upper limit on the total amount of disk space that I can assign to my VM's in KVM. Although my total partition has 200 gb, I'm not able to assign more than 20 gb to my machines - and this is not enough. The graphical virt-manager doesn't provide any guidance to this. How do I remove or change this upper limit on total VM size assigned to KVM?

Answer (score 0):

Problem identified: I have partitioned my disk into / and /home, and since the machines are located at /var/lib/libvirt/images they are at the smaller root partition.

Solution: Move the images somewhere on the /home partition and create a symbolic link (ln -s).